# Instruction pointer address from core file not in the range of function addresses listed by map file of the executable

Tags: c++, debugging, coredump, map-files

I am trying to find the location of a crash using core file and map file of the executable.The location of the crash as indicated by the core file is 0xb84cc923 . But map file of the executable doesn't have any entry near the location of the crash.Almost all of the function entries are in the range

0x0804de68
  0x0804de78
  0x0804de88
  0x0804de98
  0x0804dea8
  0x0804deb8
  0x0804dec8
  0x0804ded8
  0x0804dee8
  0x0804def8
  0x0804df08
  0x0804df18
  0x0804df28

Do i need to incorporate any offset in this calculation ?

Comment: That's not uncommon.  You need to look at the stack to find out how and where the jump/call to an illegal address came from.

Comment: Oh, +1 just for attempting some debugging - something that is getting increasingly rare:(

Comment: ..and it may als be that the crash happened in a system call that really is at that address in virtual memory:(

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for the inputs.As you pointed out, the crash is happening at a dynamic library(.so) loaded by the executable.Did an ldd on the executable which gave away the culprit.